# Why are version control menus missing from my Qt Creator?

Tags: version-control, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 3.2.2 (opensource). I have configured my version control in Tools >> Options >> Version Control >> Perforce but I don't see version control related menu issues that the documentations says is there in tools menu?

My tools menu just don't have any version control related menu options including git, cvs, subversion, it has nothing. What do I need to do to bring these in?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, and found this, unhelpfully, while searching for the fix.
I know this is nearly a year late, but just in case other poor souls have this problem, here is how I fixed it:

Go to **Help->about plugins**. Scroll to "version control". If it is as it was for me, you will find all the plugins disabled. Simply activate them and reboot QT.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to post full answer later but I had figured this out. The menus don't appear by default but they will automatically appear once you setup a particular version control. You have to set the port number and client in Options >> 'Version Control', Perforce tab.